# Joining 2 tables and creating corresponding columns

Tags: python, dataframe, join

I have 2 DataFrames as defined below:

```
from numpy import nan
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}, 'Description': {0: 'Apple', 1: 'Book', 2: 'Cat'}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'David', 1: 'Ken'},'ID1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B'}, 'ID2': {0: 'C', 1: nan}, 'ID3': {0: 'B', 1: 'C'}})

# df1
  ID Description
0  A       Apple
1  B        Book
2  C         Cat

# df2
    Name    ID1  ID2  ID3
0   David   A    C    B
1   Ken     B   NaN   C
```

I want to join ID of table1 to ID1, ID2, ID3 of table 2 and add corresponding columns DESC1, DESC2, DESC3:

```
  Name    ID1  DESC1  ID2  DESC2 ID3  DESC3
0 David   A    Apple   C    Cat   B   Book
1 Ken     B    Book    NaN  Null  C   Cat
```

Thinking about a for-loop to do that efficiently but do not know how to do about. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is the input? You used the [tag:dataframe] tag but show dictionaries.

Comment: Sorry the output should be a df but I don't know how to add a df in my question, then I use dictionary instead.

Comment: I updated the question with the correct format

Comment: I just realize that my df2 has other columns such as Name and I want to keep those columns. I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), first [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
out = (
 df2.melt(ignore_index=False, var_name='col', value_name='ID')
    .assign(col=lambda d: d['col'].str.extract(r'(\d+)'))
    .reset_index()
    .merge(df1.rename(columns={'Description': 'DESC'}), how='left')
    .pivot(index='index', columns='col')
    .sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)
    .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.map(''.join), axis=1))
)
```

Or with a simple loop and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([df2[[col]].rename(columns={col: 'ID'}).merge(df1)
                           .add_suffix(col.removeprefix('ID'))
                 for col in df2], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      ID1  DESC1  ID2 DESC2 ID3 DESC3
index                                
0       A  Apple    C   Cat   B  Book
1       B   Book  NaN   NaN   C   Cat
```

##### handling extra columns

Add the other columns to the index temporarily:

```
cols = ['Name']

out = (
 df2.rename_axis('index').set_index(cols, append=True)
    .melt(ignore_index=False, var_name='col', value_name='ID')
    .assign(col=lambda d: d['col'].str.extract(r'(\d+)'))
    .reset_index()
    .merge(df1.rename(columns={'Description': 'DESC'}), how='left')
    .pivot(index=['index']+cols, columns='col')
    .sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)
    .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.map(''.join), axis=1))
    .reset_index(cols)
)
```

With `concat`:

```
out = df2[cols].join(
       pd.concat([df2[[col]].rename(columns={col: 'ID'}).merge(df1)
                            .add_suffix(col.removeprefix('ID'))
                  for col in df2.drop(columns=cols)], axis=1)
      )
```

Output:

```
        Name ID1  DESC1  ID2 DESC2 ID3 DESC3
index                                       
0      David   A  Apple    C   Cat   B  Book
1        Ken   B   Book  NaN   NaN   C   Cat
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway. The first solution works well. Can you please give me more explanation about that? For some reason, the concat solution did not produce expected result.

Comment: `melt` enables to reshape the ID columns from wide to long format, then we `merge` on ID, finally we reshape back to a wide format with `pivot`. I suggest you command all the lines and uncomment them one by one to see the intermediates.

Comment: Thank you. Yes looking at intermediates helps

Comment: That's why chained commands are nice, you can easily do that ;)

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the desired output, you can directly create a dictionary (let's call it `dic`) with keys and values like `'A': 'Apple'`. Then, iterate through the `ID` dictionary and replace the keys with their corresponding values to create the `desc` dictionary. Finally, *merge the ID and description dictionaries into one.* In this explanation, Table1 and Table2 refer to `a` and `b` respectively.

Code:

```
dic = {value: a['Description'][key] for key, value in a['ID'].items()}    #output : {'A': 'Apple', 'B': 'Book', 'C': 'Cat'}

{**b, **{key.replace('ID', 'DESC') : {k: dic.get(v, 'null') for k, v in val.items()} for key, val in b.items()}}
```

Output:

```
{'ID1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B'},
 'ID2': {0: 'C', 1: nan},
 'ID3': {0: 'B', 1: 'C'},
 'DESC1': {0: 'Apple', 1: 'Book'},
 'DESC2': {0: 'Cat', 1: 'null'},
 'DESC3': {0: 'Book', 1: 'Cat'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for the unclear. The output would be a df.